# query to incrementally count with resets on certain condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

consider a table with the following schema:

```
device_id VARCHAR
date      DATE
visited   BOOLEAN
```

let's say that the data in the table covers a time period of 30 days and for every `device_id` there are going to be 30 rows, one for each day of the month (so, if we have 10 devices, there will be 10x30=300 rows).

I need to write a query where the result set will contain one additional integer field called `age`, where `age` is calculated like this: if `visited` is `TRUE`, then `age` should be set to `0`.  For other rows for a given `device_id`, `age` should be incremented by `1` for each consecutive day.  So the result should look something like this:

```
device_id   date         visited     age
aaaa        2018/05/01    True       0
aaaa        2018/05/02    False      1
aaaa        2018/05/03    False      2
aaaa        2018/05/04    False      3
aaaa        2018/05/05    False      4
aaaa        2018/05/06    True       0
aaaa        2018/05/07    False      1
aaaa        2018/05/08    False      2
aaaa        2018/05/09    False      3
aaaa        2018/05/10    False      4
...
aaaa        2018/05/31    False     15
bbbb        2018/05/01    True       0
...
```

I've been trying to use a window function to rank the records, but there is really no consistent partition to rank over.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use windowed `SUM` to prepare groups within device_id and `COUNT`/`ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(visited::int) OVER(PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY date) AS grp
  FROM tab
)
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY device_id,grp ORDER BY date)-1AS age
FROM cte
ORDER BY device_id, date;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a43e4f76a9a898f8c169c7b9d70190b1)**